# query select max with mixed string and int

Tags: mysql, select, max, mixed

I have a table which contain a column for generated code, the data type is VARCHAR with mixed string/int values like :

```
Table demo
ID        code
==============
1      |  001qwe
2      |  002qwe
3      |  001asd
```

Question :

1. How to get max value that contain `qwe` or `asd`, i want it used as filter.

2. How to get id of row which contain the maxed value

i want something like :

```
select *,MAX(SUBSTRING(code, 1, 3)) from demo where SUBSTRING(code, 4, 3) = 'asd'
```

Comment: code length will always be of 6 characters? Or no.s in code will be first 3 or they can appear in middle or at the end of string ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Yes this case code length is 6 and number is 3 digit in the beginning of data.

Comment: You should split the `code` column into two different columns: one for the number, another one for the string. This way the query will run much faster (and it will be easier to read and understand).

Comment: @axiac , yes i loved to and that is what on my mind. but assume current case we cannot add additional column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes this case code length is 6 and number is 3 digit in the beginning of data

Considering above you can write your query as below

```
select *,left(`code`,3)
from demo
order by left(`code`,3) * 1 desc
limit 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e3ba/5)

to get individual results you can use following

```
SELECT a.id qweid, a.code qwecode,b.id asdid,b.code asdcode
FROM 
(SELECT id,`code`
FROM demo
WHERE RIGHT(`code`,3) = 'qwe'
ORDER BY LEFT(`code`,3) * 1 DESC
LIMIT 1) a
CROSS JOIN(SELECT id,`code`
FROM demo
WHERE RIGHT(`code`,3) = 'asd'
ORDER BY LEFT(`code`,3) * 1 DESC
LIMIT 1) b
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e3ba/13)

Comment: How to get max value that contain `qwe` or `asd` ?
Max of qwe is 2 yes it is correct.
Max of asd is 1

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, yes thats it, even though no need to cross join. Thank you very much.